# Unable to copy all data in column - excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to copy all data in a specific column and paste it into another sheet in my workbook through VBA as this is to be repeated across multiple columns. For some reason - not all data gets transferred, as there are some blanks some data. My code in VBA is as below.

Am new to VBA, appreciate everyone's help, thank you!

wsRawT and wsDetI are my defined variables for the specified worksheet..

```
wsRawT.Select
    range("AU1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).range("A1").Select
    range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.copy

wsDetI.Select
    range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: `End(xlDown)` moves to the cell immediately above the first empty cell below the source cell. I.e. everything below the first blank cell will not be copied. To topy the whole column until the last non-empty cell you must search for data end from the last cell of `sheet.usedrange` to `xlUp` direction. Test: fill A1,A2,A4,A5 (A3 remain empty), select A1, perform `Selection.End(xlDown).Select` - A2 (not A5!) will be selected.

Comment: But, because you need to copy starting from 2nd row, it seems to be more simple: store value of the cell in row 1, copy whole column, restore one cell value.

Comment: You need to work with LAST ROW method to Copy & Paste data from sheet Column to another.

Comment: Side note: in general it's best to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code

Comment: @Akina Hi! I actually tried this but I couldnt get it to work to select everything in that row to be copied over.

Comment: @RajeshS hi! may you kindly elaborate how to go about this? I'm having trouble understanding the LAST ROW logic ..

Comment: @faddywaddy,, the `Last Row` method finds,, the last filled row in Column.

Answer (score 0):

```vba
Sub test()
    Dim wsRawT As Worksheet, wsDetI As Worksheet
    Set wsRawT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDetI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    wsRawT.Range(wsRawT.Cells(2, 47), wsRawT.Cells(wsRawT.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 47)).Copy _
           Destination:=wsDetI.Cells(2, 1)

End Sub
```

PS. `Range("AU2").Column = 47`

Comment: I received a run time error '1004' for this - as method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed. thanks for your patience ....

Comment: @faddywaddy Where does you have placed this procedure into? does it is common module (not worksheet or class/form module)?

Comment: this is just part of one module

Comment: @faddywaddy Test it separately at first (for example by `CALL test()` instead of your code part). If no problems then integrate it into your code carefully (or simply call it from your code, maybe transferring sheets references and/or addresses into as parameters).

Comment: `Cells(2, 47)` and `Cells(wsRawT.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 47)` do not necessarily belong to `wsRawT` and should not be considered reliable start and stop references for `wsRawT.Range`. Put all of these inside a `With ... End With` block.

Comment: @Jeeped Oops... you're right. 'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

A userform can be used for column copying. The userform contains two listboxes.
The column headings on sheet1 are listed on first listbox.In between the list boxes,the item moves from listbox1 to listbox2 by clicking the button.
 . The selected columns from listbox2 are copied to other sheet (sheet2) with Advanced Filter method.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim FirstCell, LastCell As Range
Dim basliklar As Integer
Dim baslangic_satiri As Long
Sheets("report").Select
If ListBox2.ListCount = 0 Then
MsgBox "You don't choose filter field "
Exit Sub
End If
ProgressDlg.Show 'Progress Bar

  Set LastCell = Sheets("database").Cells(Sheets("database").Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
      Sheets("database").Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)
  Set FirstCell = Sheets("database").Cells(Sheets("database").Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
      Sheets("database").Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

For basliklar = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
baslangic_satiri = 2
Sheets("report").Cells(baslangic_satiri - 1, basliklar + 1) = ListBox2.List(basliklar, 0)

Sheets("database").Range(FirstCell, LastCell).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("database").Range(FirstCell, LastCell), _
    CopyToRange:=Sheets("report").Cells(baslangic_satiri - 1, basliklar + 1), _
    Unique:=False
Next
Sheets("report").Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
CommandButton6.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

[image]

[Example file](https://www.technologicaltipstools.online/2015/06/excel-filtering-columns-via-userform.html)